# Is there any place to discuss already answered question on askubuntu or other stackexchange sites

Tags: discussion

I want to discuss already answered question. Is there any place to discuss it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- [Ask Ubuntu chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). You need 20 reputation though.
- [Ubuntu discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/).

  > **How's Ubuntu Discourse different from other sites?**
  >
  > Ask Ubuntu, the Ubuntu Forums, and project mailing lists are where we do our tech support. We recommend those sites for questions about how to configure and use Ubuntu. This is a place where you can share screenshots, talk about your favorite desktops and tools, and generally hang out with your Ubuntu friends in a friendly, relaxed environment.
- [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/). I would not visit the ubuntu forums unless you want to re-ask the question and re-discuss it (they probably will not accept a "look I read this on AU what do you think" type of discussion; you have to be more like as a new question with references to askubuntu).

Answer (score 9):

Yes!

As you might know, we don't really do *discussions* on the main Ask Ubuntu site, but there are places you can have them:

- The [Ask Ubuntu Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is a good place for post related discussion, but you'll need 20 rep to access it. Go edit a few questions!
- [Ubuntu Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/) a great place to discuss things, questions or otherwise.
- and then of course there is the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/), another great place for discussions.